# Find All ContentPlaceHolders in a MasterPage ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have to find the IDs of all the contentPlaceHolders in a MasterPage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through all Controls and recursively through their subcontrols and check the type and if they are contentplaceholders you have the ID.

Comment: An example would be gr8..As I am using a nested Master Page . I have written a function which takes MasterPage as Parameter and loops throus all the controls. but for some unknown reason its not able to find the ContentPlaceHolder

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question to include the code you have already written.

Answer (score 1):

Just query the `ContentPlaceHolders` property which returns an IList containing all the CPH names in the given Master page.

VB code: (Sorry!)

```
'In the Master Page.
For Each cphID As String In Me.ContentPlaceHolders
  Debug.WriteLine(cphID)
Next
```

Comment: The thing is I have to pass MasterPage as parameter to the function. I cant write a function in Master Page

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
for (string cphID in ((MasterPageType)this.MasterPage).ContentPlaceHolders)
{
   Debug.WriteLine(cphID);
}
```

In the code behind of your page, and replace MasterPageType with the type of your master page